# creating text from NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding text

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have text below,

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\cocoartf1138\cocoasubrtf510
{\fonttbl\f0\fswiss\fcharset0 Helvetica;}
{\colortbl;\red255\green255\blue255;}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww10800\viewh8400\viewkind0
\pard\
\f0\fs24 \cf0 \'83}

In the above text \'83 corresponds to RTF file  format and is in NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding. Now my problem is how to convert to actual representation in

83 corresponds to string ƒ in NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding.

NSString string with the encoding  say using the api 
stringWithCString:encoding. I have called the api like below.

```
NSString* str = [NSString stringWithCString:@"\'83" encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
```

but it does not give the text. please let me know how to convert the value to particular text.

Regards,
Lenin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@"\'83"` is not a c string, so you shouldn't be passing it to `stringWithCString:encoding:`. Even a C string version, `"\'83"`, is just ascii characters so using the encoding `NSWdindowsCP1252StringEncoding` will not produce a string with any special characters.

Instead you need a c string with non-ascii values in order for `NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding` to result in a non-ascii character like 'ƒ'.

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithCString:"\x83" encoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
```